# express-ws alternative in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, websocket

I have been searching for a few days now but still haven’t found any alternative or help writing a TypeScript Declaration for it as I also tried that.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws

Important is that it works with any other route in express. Authentication, Roles and Path Parameters.

Answer (score 10):

Typings for express-ws have now been [created](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/24984).

The [tests](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/24984/files#diff-ba196bd5789473c30b71e9d43099c676) show how to use it:

```
import expressWs from 'express-ws';
const { app, getWss, applyTo } = expressWs(express());
```

Or:

```
const app = expressWs(express()).app;
```

Then for example when declaring routes rather than writing:

```
const myRoutes = function(app: Express) {...}
```

You need to specify the express-ws type:

```
import expressWs from 'express-ws';
const myRoutes = function(app: expressWs.Application) {...}
```

Answer (score 6):

Thanks **Derek Hill** and **Normunds Kalnberzins**

Works with routers is better

First import express-ws

```
import expressWs from 'express-ws';
```

To use the `ws` method, you need to strengthen express (I understand it this way)

```
const { app, getWss, applyTo } = expressWs(express());
```

after that
`express.Router` contains the `ws` method, but the type of the typescript is wrong, you only need to convert the type.

```
const router = express.Router() as expressWs.Router;
```

Define the routing logic

```
router.ws('/echo', (ws, req) => {
    ws.on('message', (msg: String) => {
        ws.send(msg);
    });
});
```

Finally add `router` to the express `app`

```
app.use("/ws-stuff", router);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is that `Router` type has no `ws(...)` method. Add

```
export interface RouterWs extends express.Router {
  ws (route: string, ...cb): RouterWs; 
}
```

Then later when getting `Router` just cast it as your type.

```
const router = express.Router() as RouterWs;
router.ws('/somepath', (ws, req) => {...
```